# How to upload a file with meteor on form submit?

Tags: javascript, meteor, file-upload

I want to upload a file with meteor on form submit, because there are other input fields with data linked to the file. This code given in the [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) docs works fine on the `change` event:

**JS**

```
Template.myForm.events({
  'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
    var files = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, ln = files.length; i < ln; i++) {
      Images.insert(files[i], function (err, fileObj) {
        // Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <form class="new-task">
    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
    <input type="file" name="image" class="myFileInput">
  </form>
```

How to adapt `var files = event.target.files;` when the event is changed to `submit form`? Where are the files, can't find them anywhere in the event.

Comment: have you tested it with `'submit form': function (event) {console.log(event.target['image'].files);}`

Comment: @Thai Tran: I tested it with `event.target['image'].files`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Thai Tran's. From his answer, following worked for me:

```
event.target['image'].files
```

more over if someone wants it to get file's list with jQuery (class selector), it's like:

```
$(".myFileInput")[0].files
```